# Barplot: xlab and ylab does not work

Tags: r, bar-chart

Can anybody explain me, why my ylab does not appear?

```
barplot(structured_data, # matrix with 2x2 data
    main = "aString",las = 2,
    legend = c("Fragezeichen gesehen", "Fragezeichen nicht gesehen"),col = c("cadetblue", "dodgerblue4"),
    ylab = "Anteil der Teilnehmer (in %)")
```

Comment: It does appear. I do not see any issue.

Comment: This does work in a normal R installation. Perhaps you have modified some of your graphical parameters (`mai` or `mar` maybe), so that the y label appears outside the plotting region?

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!